# Problemas con react-native-maps

Tags: react-native

soy algo nuevo en react-native, estoy usando expo y estoy haciendo una app de localizacion de tiendas, el icono lo traigo desde un servidor al igual que todos los marcadores, el icono esta en base64, el problema es que carga aproximadamente 100 y se pone muy lenta la navegacion por el mapa, pero la verdad no encuentro documentacion para hacer que vaya cargado iconos a medida que vaya navegando por el sitio, para que pueda traer de 10 o 20 marcadores, alguien tiene alguna idea acerca de como puedo hacer? muchas gracias de antemano

mi código es el siguiente

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity, Image, TouchableHighlight, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import MapView, { Marker, watchPosition, PROVIDER_GOOGLE, AnimatedRegion } from 'react-native-maps'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import { AuthSession, Linking } from 'expo';
import haversine from 'haversine';

const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.009
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.009
var screen = Dimensions.get('window');


var mapStyle = [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
const url = 'mi direccion de servidor'



export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            initialPosition: {
                latitude: 4.713846,
                longitude: -74.057160,
                latitudeDelta: 0.5,
                longitudeDelta: 0.01
            },
            markerPosition: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0
            },
            onRegionChange: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0
            },
            geocode: [],
            markers: [],
            infoClient: [],
            photoClient: []
        }
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    modal = React.createRef();


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLocation()
    }

    getLocation = async() => {
        let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        if (status !== 'granted') {
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
        });
        }

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})
        let geocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords);
        var lat = parseFloat(location.coords.latitude)
        var long = parseFloat(location.coords.longitude)
        var initialRegion = {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }

        this.setState({
            initialPosition: initialRegion,
            markerPosition: initialRegion,
            geocode: geocode
        })
        // this.getMarkers()
    };

    resetLocation = async() => {
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})
        var lat = parseFloat(location.coords.latitude)
        var long = parseFloat(location.coords.longitude)

        var initialRegion = {
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: long,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }

        this.setState({
          initialPosition: initialRegion,
          markerPosition: initialRegion
        })
    };

    setZoom = (data, markerId) => {
        var initialRegion = {
        latitude: data.latitude,
        longitude: data.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }

        this.setState({
        initialPosition: initialRegion
        })
        this.goToMarker(markerId)
    }
    
    goToMarker = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            infoClient: [],
            photoClient: []
        })
        var datos = {
            id: data
        }
        fetch(url+'getInfoClient', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(datos),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((info) => {
                this.setState({
                    infoClient: info
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                fetch(url+'getPhotoClient', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(datos),
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then((info) => {
                        this.setState({
                            photoClient: info
                        })
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.refs.modal6.open()
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err))
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    goStore = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Client', {
            city: this.state.geocode[0].isoCountryCode
        })
    }

    goLiquid = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Liquid', {
        city: this.state.geocode[0].isoCountryCode
      })
    }

    goEquip = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Equip', {
        city: this.state.geocode[0].isoCountryCode
      })
    }

    goAccesorios = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Accesorios', {
        city: this.state.geocode[0].isoCountryCode
      })
    }
  

    onRegionChangeComplete(region) {
      var posicionActual = {
        latitude: region.latitude,
        longitude: region.longitude
      }
      var datos = {
        actual: posicionActual
      }
      fetch(url+'getMarkerToFilter', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(datos),
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then((info) => {
            this.setState({
              markers: info
            })
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
      // console.log(haversine(initial, final, {unit: 'meter'}))
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              initialPosition={this.state.initialPosition}
              initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}
              customMapStyle={mapStyle}
              showsUserLocation
              onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this)}
              showsCompass={false}
              ref={map => {this.map = map}}
              showsBuildings={false}
              showsTraffic={false}
              showsIndoors={false}
              showsMyLocationButton={true}
              // onRegionChange={() => this.handleCenter()}
              // ref={mapRef => mapRef===null ? null : mapRef.fitToElements(true) }
            >
            {this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
                var lat = parseFloat(marker.latitud, 6)
                var lon = parseFloat(marker.longitud, 6)
                return(
                <Marker
                    key={marker.id}
                    title={marker.nombre}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon
                    }}
                    onPress={() => this.setZoom({
                      latitude: lat,
                      longitude: lon
                    }, marker.id)}
                >
                  <Image 
                    source={marker.marker === '' ? require('./puntero.png') : {uri: marker.marker}}
                    style={{ width: 50, height: 70 }}
                  />
                  <MapView.Callout style={{marginBottom: 5, width: 150}} onPress= {()=> this.goToMarker(marker.id)}>
                    <TouchableOpacity underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                      <View>
                        <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>{marker.nombre}{'\n'}{'Click para saber más'}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </MapView.Callout>
                </Marker>
                )
            })}
            </MapView>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.storeStyle} activeOpacity={0.5}>
              <Icon
                  name='store'
                  color='#FFF'
                  size= {30} 
                  onPress={() => this.goStore()}
                  underlayColor= '#083A18'
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.coilStyle} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.goAccesorios()}>
              <Image
                  style={styles.imgCoil}
                  source={require('./coil.png')}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.liquidStyle} activeOpacity={0.5}>
              <Icon
                  name='eyedropper'
                  type='material-community'
                  color='#FFF'
                  size= {30} 
                  onPress={() => this.goLiquid()}
                  underlayColor= '#9C8351'
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.vapeStyle} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.goEquip()}>
              <Image
                  style={styles.imgVape}
                  source={require('./vape-white.png')}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.locationStyle} activeOpacity={0.5}>
              <Icon
                  name='my-location'
                  color='#FFF'
                  size= {30}
                  onPress={() => this.resetLocation()}
                  underlayColor= '#F32525'
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modalCliente]} position={"bottom"} ref={"modal6"} swipeArea={20}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.containerModal}>
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                            <Icon
                                name='close-circle-outline'
                                type='material-community'
                                color='#000'
                                size= {40} 
                                onPress={() => this.refs.modal6.close()}
                                underlayColor= '#fff'
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.headerModal}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.imgInfo}
                                source={{uri: this.state.infoClient.length === 0 ? null : this.state.infoClient[0].logo}}
                            />
                            <Text style={styles.titulo}>{this.state.infoClient.length === 0 ? null : this.state.infoClient[0].nombre}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.bodyModal}>
                            <ScrollView
                                horizontal
                                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                scrollEventThrottle={10}
                            >
                                {this.state.photoClient.map((foto) => {
                                    return(
                                        <View key={foto.id}>
                                            <Image
                                                style={styles.images} 
                                                source={{uri: this.state.photoClient.length === 0 ? null : foto.image}}
                                            />
                                        </View>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </ScrollView>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                        {this.state.infoClient.length === 0 ? null :
                            <View style={styles.footModal}>
                                <Text style={styles.textModal}>Dirección: {this.state.infoClient[0].direccion}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.textModal}>Teléfono: {this.state.infoClient[0].telefono}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.textModal}>Parqueadero disponible: {this.state.infoClient[0].parqueadero}</Text>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(this.state.infoClient[0].web)}><Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#7F7EAD'}}>{this.state.infoClient[0].web}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        }
                        </View>
                        <View>
                        <Icon
                            name='whatsapp'
                            type='material-community'
                            color='#009F29'
                            size= {40} 
                            onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://wa.me/+'+this.state.infoClient[0].whatsapp)}
                            underlayColor= '#fff'
                        />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </Modal>
        </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    storeStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 380,
        right: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#083A18',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    coilStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 310,
        right: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#303030',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    liquidStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 240,
        right: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#9C8351',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    imgLiquid: {
        height: 35,
        width: 15
    },
    vapeStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 170,
        right: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#0B3462',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    imgVape: {
        height: 35,
        width: 15
    },
    imgCoil: {
        height: 35,
        width: 35
    },
    locationStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 100,
        right: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F32525',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    modal: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    modalCliente: {
        height: 500,
        borderRadius: 10
    },
    containerModal: {
        paddingHorizontal: 5
    },
    headerModal: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    imgInfo: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    titulo: {
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: 5
    },
    bodyModal: {
        marginTop: 5
    },
    images: {
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        marginRight: 5
    },
    footModal: {
        marginTop: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    textModal: {
        fontSize: 20
    }

});
```

Comment: Muéstranos tu código para saber qué puede ser la causa de que se ponga lento el mapa. Es así para Android o para iOS o ambos?

Comment: German, gracias por responder, si señor es igual para las dos plataformas, el codigo es el siguiente, lo dejo en una respuesta, que pena no pude ponerlo aca